# Deploying C#/.NET API backend hosted on Appengine Flex to Google Cloud Endpoints and using the API exlorer

Tags: .net, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-dotnet-client, app-engine-flexible

We've got a C# back-end that hosted on an Appengine Flex(.NET runtime) we're trying to deploy this to Google Cloud Endpoints and use the API explorer, but we're not able to find documentation on this.

Can someone point us in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

It should work like any other app deployed on Flex. Can you explain what you've tried?

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine-dotnet is the tutorial for deploying an Endpoints service written with .NET. Have you read this tutorial?